# Python How to sort values when they are all in body?

Tags: python, extract

```js
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


start_time = time.time()
url = 'https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=zezima'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'}

resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print("Server: " + resp.headers['server'])
print(resp.text)
print("Job done in" + " %f seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I am trying to learn how to sort the different values (their stats) and do e.g.
total level: 1465
The stats are always in the same order, and is -1 if nothing is found.
I want it to only output the total level which is the second value. In this case, 1465.
Ideal output would be something like this:

Total level: 1465

Sample response:

```
690953,1465,27957906
711820,76,1343681
658073,76,1342072
1033645,75,1271864
1091165,75,1252551
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a case of simply splitting on newlines, then splitting the first line on commas.

```
lines = resp.text.split('\n')
first_line = lines[0].split(',')
print('Total level: ' + first_line[1] )
```

You can add some error checking if there is not always a result.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import requests 
 import bs4 
 import time

 url  = 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html' # this link will be usefull 
 its made for webscraping , and all price is fake 
 # you can practies on this website ...
 start  = time.time()

 req = requests.get(url)
 soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml') # using BeautifulSoup for sorting html 
 #script

 end = time.time()
 print("Job done in" + " %f seconds" % (end - start))

#if you want something in the website if it was class use (.) before the stuf  if we 
want product price of first page of books
product_price = soup.select('.price_color')

for i in product_price:
print('price = ' +i.getText())
```